# Searches items based on tags java string array

Tags: java, arrays, database, string, for-loop

****This is the output****

run:

Search: Pet Cute

---Result—-

1. Cat 2pts
2. Chicken 1pts

Search: Cold Food

---Result—-

1. Ice Cream 2pts
2. Burger  1pts
3. Chicken 1pts

Search: Hot Gadget

---Result—-

1.Burger 1pts

2.Laptop 1pts

****This is the given code and items****

```
 String [][] data={{"Cat","Pet Mammal Cute"},
         {"Burger","Food Snack Hot"},
         {"Chicken","Food Bird Pet"},
         {"Ice Cream","Food Dessert Cold"},
         {"Laptop","Gadget Device Computer"},
                   };
```

****I just took this code from stackoverflow and its similar to mine but dont repeat the word and no pts.****

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.print("Search : " ); 
String getInput=scan.nextLine(); 
String []in; int counter=0; 
String oldData=""; in = getInput.split(" "); 
for (String[] data1 : data) { 
String []container= data1[1].split(" "); 
for(int i=0;i<in.length ;i++){ 
for (String container1 : container) 
{ if (in[i].equals(container1)) 
{ oldData=oldData +"\n"+ data1[0]; } } } } 
System.out.print("RESULT\n---" + (oldData)); } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code makes 3 attempts of searching and counts the points:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
    System.out.print("Search : ");
    String getInput = scan.nextLine();
    String[] in = getInput.split(" ");
    Map<String, Integer> results = new HashMap<>();

    for (String[] row : data) {
        for (String searchWord : in) {
            if (row[1].contains(searchWord)) {
                int count = results.get(row[0]) == null ? 0 : results.get(row[0]).intValue();

                results.put(row[0], count + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("RESULT\n---");
    int i = 0;
    for (String word : results.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(++i + ". " + word + " " + results.get(word) + " pts");
    }
}
```